# Docstring issue in R

Tags: r, docstring

I am unable to view the comments which are in the doctring  in R, for example
**I have name the function earlier square and was able to view ?square** and then changed function name to ab and then try to view the docstring **?ab** , I am unable to do so.

[image]

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))
library(docstring)
ab <- function(a){
  #' @title :square function
  #' @description : print the squares of the number 
  #'from 1 to the input given
  #' @param : input number
  #' @output : provide the squares of the input range
  for(i in 1:a){
    b <- i^2
    print(b)
  }
}
?ab
```

I am not sure why this is happening , I would appreciate if some could help me on this

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Your code works on my setup. Try restarting R and running again?

Comment: roxygen comments don't work the same way as docstrings in Python.  I'd recommend reading Wickham's *R Packages* book, which is available online ... (unless RStudio, which I don't use, does some kind of magic with them ...)

Comment: Just open an issue here: https://github.com/dasonk/docstring/issues

Comment: @AllanCameron, https://imgur.com/a/ob3ool3  ,

if you see the link I am able to get the o/p when I use square function by using ?square but when I try to rename and try to use ?ab I can't get

Comment: @LuciusHu 
- already did here too 

https://github.com/Dasonk/docstring/issues/27

Comment: @Dexter_1234 Since this package use `roxygen2` under the hood. I'd give `roxygen2::roxygenize` a try. I'm not sure how `docstring` is implemented, chances are it failed to detect that the docs has changed.

Comment: @LuciusHu tried installing roxygen2 but it failed ,


Error: Failed to install 'roxygen2' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/KARTIK~1.BAP/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoVs0MY/file32783699224d/roxygen2_7.1.1.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @Dason can you help

Comment: What error did you see?

Comment: @LuciusHu I tried installing roxygen2 but was not able to now when I am trying to run doctring , I am getting this error Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘docstring’:
 package ‘roxygen2’ does not have a namespace